# Why my backgroung-image is not displaying in website?

Tags: html, css

My HTML CODE:

```
<div class="top__background-1">
    <div>
        <h1>NRRN CONCRETE UDHYOG</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

MY CSS CODE:

```css
/* linear-gradient is displaying but image is not being displaying */
.top__background-1 {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    height: 40rem;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#355b7d98, #355b7d93), url(/Images/cover.jpg);
}
.top__background-1 h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20rem;
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Is the relative path `/Images/cover.jpg` correct from you css location? Any hints in your developer console?

Comment: See this test case here (which works): https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/njf7zb8o/1/ . Please make sure that your path to the image is correct

Comment: Where is `cover.jpg` placed in the directory structure relatively to your HTML and CSS ?

Comment: Try `Images/cover.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution, when you want display your image from a directory which is in the same location, you no need to write "/" before "Image", you should add path like that: "Images/cover.jpg" for more result I want to show you with images..
i have little edited something in your CSS code

```
.top__background-1 {
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
height: 40rem;
background-position: center;
background-size:cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(25, 34, 83, 0.7), rgba(57, 70, 145, 0.7)), url(Images/cover.jpg);}
```

1. I have made 2 CSS and HTML files and one Folder where is a cover.jpg image
   [image: I have made 2 CSS and HTML files and one Folder where is a cover.jpg image]
2. added 2 codes, background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; I added background-position with a "center" parameter because my jpg image needs to be with center position, also removed "/" before "Image", also changed HEX colors with RGBA for transparency, because if color code is hex and you want to add gradient colors on image, they should be with transparent mode which have RGBA parameter.
   [image: added 2 codes, background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; I added background-position with a "center" parameter because my jpg image needs to be with center position, also removed "/" before "Image"]
3. So I think there is a result which you needed, I hope I helped you :)
   [image: So I think there is a result which you needed, I hope I helped you :)]

Comment: Thanks a lot loane !! it worked perfectly. i was really stuck in this problem. finally it is solved !!! :)

Comment: You are welcome Mrpratik, I am glad to help you :)!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not referencing correctly your image. I tried exactly the same CSS and HTML (except that I changed the image for on in my computer) and it worked. `/Images/cover.jpg` references `your.domain/Images/cover.jpg`. Maybe using `./Images/cover.jpg` or `Images/cover.jpg` (both referencing the Images folder located in the same folder as the HTML/CSS) would work ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several points

1. You haven't got the right path for your image. Your current path to the image is `DOMAIN/Images/cover.jpg`. But I think the folder with all of your images is where your HTML lies, right?
2. Don't forget the ' around your URL. Maybe this is a problem for your browser.
3. Change `background-image` to `background` because you can't use a `linear-gradient` in a `background-image`
   If this is so, you need to change the `background-image` line to this:

```css
background: linear-gradient(#355b7d98, #355b7d93), url('./Images/cover.jpg');
```

```css
/* linear-gradient is displaying but image is not being displaying */

.top__background-1 {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 40rem;
  background-size: cover;
  background: linear-gradient(#355b7d98, #355b7d93), url('./Images/cover.jpg');
}

.top__background-1 h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20rem;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="top__background-1">
  <div>
    <h1>NRRN CONCRETE UDHYOG</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Rather than using background image use only background property something like this**

```css
background:linear-gradient(#355b7d98, #355b7d93), url('/Images/cover.jpg');
```

Comment: I have tested, it's working fine. Please tell me problem you are facing currently